# Nginx - redirect correctly from http:// to https:// without www

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

Following my configuration file:

```
server {
   listen [::]:443 ipv6only=off ssl;
   server_name www.example.com;
   // ssl stuff
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen  [::]:80 ipv6only=off;
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen [::]:443 ssl;  
   server_name example.com;
   // php and ssl stuff
}
```

I don't understand why `http://www.example.com` redirects to `https://www.example.com` and then to `https://example.com`. How to redirect from `http://www.example.com` directly to `https://example.com`?

Comment: Do you have HSTS enabled ? If yes, then the first redirect is done directly by your browser without any network interaction, so there is nothing to worry.

Comment: @Tom yes! Good to know! Thank you a lot.

Comment: So I let you update your question add HSTS and validate my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HSTS enabled, the first redirect is done directly by your browser without any network interaction.

Answer (score 1):

NGINX config for redirect from HTTP to HTTPS without WWW:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen  [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
   listen 443 default_server;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
   server_name example.com www.example.com;
   ##here-ssl-settings##
   return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```